# RxSwift - multiple Observable value within one Observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to make a function like this example.

**example**

```
let num1 = Driver<Int>
let num2 = Driver<Int>
let result = Driver<String>

num1 = Observable.just(...).asDriver()
num2 = Observable.just(...).asDriver()
result = ??? // When both num1 and num2 are subscribed, this becomes a higher value among them as String.

// This type of code will be used
/* 
if $0 >= $1 {
    return "num1 = \($0)"
} else {
    return "num2 = \($1)"
}
*/
```

How to implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a Variable if you can help it. You already have a couple of observables so use them, but yes, `combineLatest` is the solution here:

```
import RxSwift

let num1 = Observable.just(3)
let num2 = Observable.just(5)
let result = Observable.combineLatest(num1, num2).map { $0 >= $1 ? "num1 = \($0)" : "num2 = \($1)" }

_ = result.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

The above prints "num2 = 5" when it's placed in a properly configured playground.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this!

Answer (score 5):

You can use RxSwift `Variable` here instead of the `Driver`and to to listen on the two Observables, you can use `Observable.combineLatest(..)` 
method.
Below is an example how you can achieve it:

```
let num1: Variable<Int>!
let num2: Variable<Int>!

let bag = DisposeBag()

num1 = Variable(1)
num2 = Variable(2)

let result = Observable.combineLatest(num1.asObservable(), num2.asObservable()) { (n1, n2) -> String in

    if n1 >= n2 {
        return "num1 = \(n1)"
    } else {
        return "num2 = \(n2)"
    }
}

result.subscribe(onNext: { (res) in
    print("Result \(res)")
}).addDisposableTo(bag)

num1.value = 5
num1.value = 8
num2.value = 10
num2.value = 7
```

It outputs:

```
Result num2 = 2
Result num1 = 5
Result num1 = 8
Result num2 = 10
Result num1 = 8
```

Comment: Thanks! but in my case, `num1` and `num2` should also be able to subscribe other variables. My problem was solved through other answer, but your answer also helped me understand RxSwift.